# Distutils causes protobuf to fail

Tags: c++, python-3.x, protocol-buffers, cython, distutils

I have a simple .proto as follows:

```
syntax = "proto2";

package p2p;

message  dataFrame {
repeated int64 row_label = 1;
repeated int64 col_label = 2;

message data_frame_row {
    repeated int32 column = 1;
}

repeated data_frame_row row = 3;
}
```

which I compile with protoc.

I can compile and use the following (simplified) cpp code (transitMatrix.h #includes "p2p.pb.h"):

```
#include "transitMatrix.h"

int main()
{

transitMatrix matrix(5, true);
matrix.addEdgeToGraph(0, 1, 5, true);
matrix.addEdgeToGraph(1, 2, 6, true);

matrix.writeTMX("outfile.tmx");
return 0;
}
```

However, the transitMatrix class is intended to be cythonized with distutils.

In my (simplified) test.pyx file, I cdef extern both the transitMatrix class and the dataFrame class:

```
cdef extern from "src/utils/serializer/p2p.pb.cc" namespace "p2p":
    cdef cppclass dataFrame:
        dataFrame()


cdef extern from "src/transitMatrix.h":

    cdef cppclass transitMatrix:
        transitMatrix()
```

And in my setup.py, the distutils Extension is as follows:

```
EXTENSION = distutils.extension.Extension(
name = 'test', language = 'c++',
sources = ['test.pyx'],
extra_compile_args = ['-Wno-unused-function', 
                      '-std=c++11', '-Wall', '-O3', '-lprotobuf'
                      ] + ouff_mac,
undef_macros       = ["NDEBUG"],
extra_link_args    = ouff_mac
)
```

When I run python3 setup.py install, it succeeds but warns:

```
clang: warning: -lprotobuf: 'linker' input unused
```

Finally, when I try to import the generated class in iPython (transitMatrixAdapter), I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/transitMatrixAdapter.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found:   __ZN6google8protobuf7Message20DiscardUnknownFieldsEv
Referenced from: /Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transitMatrixAdapter.cpython-36m-darwin.so
Expected in: flat namespace in /Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transitMatrixAdapter.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

I should add that this works as expected when the protobuf dependency is removed. Why is the .so not found? I presume this is a linker error, but where is the issue?

Comment: -lprotobuf should be in extra link args, as clang tries to warn you

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much